# Laravel Homestead and Access Denied

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I thought this would be easy but apparently it is not, at least for me. After following the documentation (or thinking I have) I have created a homstead vagrant box following the instructions for such and now have a homestead app where I can do:

```
app-response.tracking:8080
```

But I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /public on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at app-response.tracking Port 8080
```

When do `vagrant ssh` and go look at app-response-tracking/public:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  204 Sep  3 16:59 public
```

So then I think ok maybe its the `.htaccess` file like laravel suggests it might be.

So first I try and throw a five hundred and I throw in some garbage I replace everything in the `.htaccess` file with `sjdfhgs` reload and expect to see my broken 500, **nope still the same error.**

So then I replace the content back to what they were knowing this wont change a thing.

My `Homestead.yml` looks like, which on my mac is stored at `~/.homestead/Homestead.yml`

```
$ cat ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml 
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/laravel-projects/app-response-tracking
      to: /home/vagrant/app-response-tracking

sites:
    - map: app-response.tracking
      to: /home/vagrant/app-tesponse-tracking/public

databases:
    - app_response_tracking

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I access the site via `app-response.tracking:8080` Even doing `app-response.tracking:8080/public` fails. I still get the same error.

On vagrant, when I do `la -lah` I see:

```
$ ls -lah
total 156K
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  816 Sep  3 16:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Sep  3 16:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  374 Sep  3 16:50 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1.7K Sep  3 16:50 artisan
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  170 Sep  3 16:50 bootstrap
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1.2K Sep  3 16:50 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 103K Sep  3 16:52 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  476 Sep  3 16:50 config
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  204 Sep  3 16:50 database
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  323 Sep  3 16:53 .env
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  307 Sep  3 16:50 .env.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   61 Sep  3 16:50 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   57 Sep  3 16:50 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  503 Sep  3 16:50 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  159 Sep  3 16:50 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   87 Sep  3 16:50 phpspec.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  899 Sep  3 16:50 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  204 Sep  3 16:59 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1.9K Sep  3 16:50 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  170 Sep  3 16:50 resources
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  567 Sep  3 16:50 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  170 Sep  3 16:50 storage
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  136 Sep  3 16:50 tests
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  986 Sep  3 16:53 vendor
```

**What is going on?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a virtual host in `/etc/hosts` just add the next line at the end of the file

```
192.168.10.10   app-response.tracking
```

Next try to visit that site on your browser without the port, this will take you to your project's directory
`http://app-response.tracking/`

I you don't want to create a virtual host you should only type `localhost:8000` on your browser or `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: I am not sure if this is progress or not but when I tried adding it to my host, and then visiting the link I got: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` When I tried `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000` I got `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ` Vagrant status sais its running.